# Socket.Receive only catchs the packets sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I do Socket.Receive immediately after a handshake but sometimes the programme hangs waiting for the packet.

```
int reciveLength = tcpSock.Receive(handShake, SocketFlags.None); 
int bitfieldLength = tcpSock.Receive(bitfeildRecive, SocketFlags.None);
```

The first is received perfectly, the second does not seem to be received. I think it is a race condition as the first is sent at "83.1969" and the second at "83.1970".

When the timeout is reached bitfeildRecive will just be 65535 bytes of 0s.

I can see the packet in Wireshark, it is only one packet. How can I get the program to catch the next packet to be send?

Is there away to do this with Socket.Receive?

Comment: From what I can gather from your question you already tried some things out. Why don't you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54880548/edit) your question and add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so we can recreate it?

Comment: Are you using UDP or TCP sockets? For TCP, the abstraction *isn't* packets (and in UDP parlance, you deal with datagrams). In TCP it's a continuous stream of bytes in both directions. If you want packets/messages, it's up to *you* to implement that atop TCP (or better usually, move to a higher level protocol that already does this for you).

Comment: `code` int reciveLength = tcpSock.Receive(handShake, SocketFlags.None);
int bitfieldLength = tcpSock.Receive(bitfeildRecive, SocketFlags.None); `code`

Two TCP messages are sent, one after the other. I am only receiving the second 10% of the time. The sever send the second message 100% of the time. It seems to be a race condition.

Comment: Edit your post and use code block to display code instead of adding them in comment

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: edited with better symptoms and the line of code in question.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, TCP doesn't do **messages**. You don't call `Send` at one end and then get a guarantee that a call to `Receive` at the other end will receive the exact set of bytes put in by that `Send`. It's just a stream of bytes. You can `Send` 50 bytes at one side and end up (theoretically) with 50 calls to receive at the other end each getting one byte. Or vice versa.

Comment: And solved questions on StackOverflow are identified by them having an *accepted answer*. Which can even be your own, but make sure you give a good description of the solution.